# The result of the HelloWorld example in Bullet Physics is not consistent with free-fall law?

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

I think the HelloWorld.cpp of Bullet Physics gives an example of free-fall.

In order to check if the result of Bullet Physics is consistent with physics law, in the HelloWorld.cpp, I changed the initial position of the sphere from "startTransform.setOrigin(btVector3(2, 10, 0));" to "startTransform.setOrigin(btVector3(2, 0, 0));", and I changed the simulation step from "//dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1.f / 60.f, 10);" to "dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(0.1f, 0, 0.1f);"

I think, after these two changes, the output will be the positions of the sphere in free-fall motion spaced by 0.1 second. I also output the linear velocity of the sphere at each simulation step. The result is:
[vx, vy, yz, px, py, pz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY8vE.png)

The first line is the initial linear velocity and position. We can find that, the velocity is consistent with the free-fall law (i.e., v = g * t), but the position (displacement) is not consistent with the free-fall law (i.e., s = g * t * t / 2).

So, I wonder that if Bullet Physics is reliable? Or did I get something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: 0.1-second steps sounds very course to me.  When I was modelling cricket ball trajectories for international matches, I was using a time step of about 0.001 seconds (as far as I recall), in order to reduce errors from stepping the position. I didn't use BulletPhysics, but I'd say it's providing you a time quantum specifically because it's approximating position rather than trying to perform integration.  Try making the time quantum smaller and you should see the error begin to converge on the mathematical prediction.  Oh, and don't assume anything is in a vacuum, ever!

Comment: Thank you very much paddy! I understand your point and I tried a simulation step of  0.001 second. However, the result did not show any "convergence" toward the mathematical prediction of free-fall law . The velocity is still right, with a sequence of "-0.01, -0.02, -0.03, ..., -0.10". Yet, the sequence of position is "-0.00001, -0.00003, -0.00006, -0.00010, ..., -0.00045, -0.00055", which is the result using 0.1s multiplied by 10000!

Comment: Is it giving you position deltas instead of absolute position?  Have you read the documentation carefully?

Comment: I did not read the documentation. Yet, I think it gives the absolute position, because the other two output coordinates keeps unchanged (not zero) during the simulation, which is exactly consistent with the prediction of free-fall law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Bullet in particular, but perhaps I can help with some general information about physics engines.

Physics engines are essentially numerical integrators. They do not produce a precise analytical solution to the kinematic equations, but rather numerically sum up the velocities at each time step to generate the positions. (And numerically sum up the accelerations/forces to produce the velocities, etc).

From the numbers that you have found, it appears that Bullet Physics is using the [Euler Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for computing the integral. This is one of the least accurate methods for computing an integral, but it is also one of the simplest, both to understand and to compute.

The velocities are accurate, because the acceleration is constant, but the positions are inaccurate, because the velocity is non-constant.

Bullet Physics isn't unreliable or wrong, it is just using an approximation that isn't particularly accurate; presumably in order to have the performance to compute real-time results in complex scenes.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the point. Yet, does this mean we must suffer the "numerical inaccuracy" if we use Bullet or any other physics engine? Is there any solution that we can use to reduce this numerical inaccuracy, especially for Bullet Physics? Like the solution proposed by paddy, although after a test I found it did not work.

Comment: @Langping: Reducing the time-step will reduce the magnitude of the error, but there will still be drift over time. If you are looking for accurate results I would suggest looking at a different physics engine that is more aimed at scientific/engineering applications, rather than real-time games. Typically game-physics engines aim to have stable results (i.e. no 'explosions' where ), but do not aim for physical accuracy. For example, Project Chrono offers a [variety of integrators](http://api.chrono.projectchrono.org/classchrono_1_1_ch_timestepper.html) with different accuracies.

Answer (score 0):

Most physics engines (including Bullet) use [semi-implicit Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method) integration which is only first order accurate. A free-fall equation is second order (y = y0 + vy0*t - 0.5*g*t^2, it has a t^2 term) and thus semi-implicit Euler is going to induce error.

In general, I would not expect physics engines to be extremely accurate (there are a lot of assumptions and approximations being made). However, they can be an acceptable model of reality depending on what you need.